# Inkscape Bezier pen

Tags: vector, inkscape, tools, pen-tool, bezier-curve

I'm facing a problem in Inkscape with the Bézier pen tool when I'm trying to connect the end of the drawing with the Bézier pen. Something strange is happening.

[image]

Comment: Is the ellipse shape (on the bezier mode toolbar) on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You have the Shape set to "Ellipse" in the Tool Controls Bar.

[image]

Set it to "None" instead.